# WPF designer can't be loaded when using x64

Tags: c#, wpf

WPF Designer loads successfully when using x86, but when using x64 I got such error:

*Error  1   Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'TerminatorConsole2.View' that is not included in the assembly.  C:\Oleg\projects\MBClient\TerminatorConsole2\View\StrategyView.xaml 5   12  TerminatorConsole2*

What's the problem and how to fix it?

```
<UserControl 
  x:Class="TerminatorConsole2.View.StrategyView"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:TerminatorConsole2.View"          <------ problem line
  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
  VerticalAlignment="Center"  
  Width="1328" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="562">
...............
```

Comment: Could you please add the xaml file listing and its code-behind?

Comment: added xaml code. code behind is default - just call to InitializeComponent()

Comment: Please make sure that `StrategyView` class (code-behind) is defined inside `TerminatorConsole2.View` namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a guess. Visual Studio is a 32bit application and it doesn't load x64 dlls correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild the solution and the error may go away. Also check additional recipes: [The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace that is not included in the assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425954/the-clr-namespace-uri-refers-to-a-namespace-that-is-not-included-in-the-assemb).