# XAML referencing local=

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, assemblies

Im in a page and want to reference some converters I created in the very same xaml.cs file. This is my header

```
<Page x:Class="recoveR.paradigmSelector"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="1366"
Title="paradigmSelector" Loaded="Page_Loaded" 
  xmlns:my="clr-namespace:recoveR;assembly=StimulationSwitcher" 
  xmlns:my1="clr-namespace:recoveR;assembly=ExerciseChooser"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:recoveR">  <---- Adding this reference
```

As you can see from he header, im in the recoveR namespace, and this is the paradigmSelector page, but when setting the reference to the local  `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:recoveR"` it complaines saying:  `Error 45  Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'recoveR' that is not included in the assembly.`

There is the header of the xaml.cs file just in case it is useful:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
// other usings

namespace recoveR
{
   public partial class paradigmSelector : Page
   {
      // my codes here
   }
}
```

Tried

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:recoveR;assembly=RecoveR"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:recoveR;"
```

none worked

Please notice that `xmlns:my1="clr-namespace:recoveR;assembly=ExerciseChooser"` did included correctly the reference (it is a user control I created) so the namespace is definitely there, despite what the error says.

**EDIT**

I noticed that if I write `xmlsn:local="` and let the autocompletion works, it even offers clr-namespace:recoveR. Written in the same way I tried in my first attempt. Even when choosing from the autocompletion, it does not work.

Comment: Please try to explain better what you mean with "local:...recoveriX" and recoveR. What's the source code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3425954/1648849) post?

Comment: edited, everywhere should be recoveR. I want to make a reference to use some converters I created in the C# code. @Bahman_Aries rebuilding did not solve the trick

Comment: Are there other build errors?

Comment: no, without the  `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:recoveR"` line everything works as spected

Comment: Try putting the `assembly` on the declaration.

Comment: edited with my tests so far, none worked

Comment: According to your notes, shouldn't it be "xmlns:local="clr-namespace:recoveR;assembly=ExerciseChooser"?

Comment: ExerciseChooser is a different dll that has been successfully referenced, as StimulationSwitcher is. The particular class I'm in is `Class="recoveR.paradigmSelector"`

Comment: Have you tried xmlns:local="clr-namespace:recoveR;assembly="  ?