# The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace

Tags: .net, wpf, namespaces

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and added two folders in the root directory.

1. Model
2. ViewModel

and two classes:

1. Printer (in Model)
2. PrinterViewModel (in ViewModel)

I have already rebuild the project. The strange is that the Model.Printer namespace will be found, but not ViewModel.PrinterViewModel.

I read already this article  [The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace that is not included in the assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425954/the-clr-namespace-uri-refers-to-a-namespace-that-is-not-included-in-the-assemb)

Comment: Restart the project. it works :-)

Comment: OMG... really? You're rigth, it works... what a buggy thing